# How to specify ignore case in when statement in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

How to specify *ignore case* in a `where` statement in [Sybase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Server_Enterprise)?

Basically I want

```
 select * from _table where _field = 'BUSY'
```

to return rows if there are any rows with values like 'BuSy' in field `_field`.

Comment: Can you define the column to use a case insensitive collation?

Comment: Nope, I have a right to use target database only in 'read-only' mode. Is that for what you asking for?

Comment: Yes. If you can't change the schema then you're probably stuck with something like LadaRaider's answer then. I guess you could try doing `where (_field LIKE 'B%' OR _field LIKE 'b%') AND UPPER(_field) = 'BUSY'` and see if that's any better.

Comment: Doesn't help execution plan at all..

Comment: Are you using Sybase ASE (Adaptive Server Enterprise) or Sybase SQL Anywhere? They are completely different database products.

Comment: Apologies for slow response. I'm using ASE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select * from _table where UPPER(_field) = 'BUSY'
```

Comment: Execution plan for this query is 18 times bigger, than for query without UPPER. I wonder if there are any other functions, or ,maybe ,  execution plan could be improved.

Comment: This is because I have index on _field, which is ignored when using UPPER

Comment: I would use the following `select * from _table where UPPER(_field) = UPPER('busy')`. Make both operands UPPER. When in parametrized query or when you have something `String.Format("select * from _table where UPPER(_field) = UPPER('{}')", query)`; this will work.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, applying function on an indexed column will not allow optimizer to use that index.
The simplest way would be to rewrite the statement to:

```
select * from _table where _field like '[bB][uU][sS][yY]'
```

this should allow the optimizer to use index.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for me. Uses table scan: "Table Scan.
Total estimated I/O cost for statement 1 (at line 1): 1550556."

Answer (score 0):

Your only choices are Transact SQL functions. [This page lists them all](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/CHDIHGDF.htm)